# UITableViewCells don't receive setEditing message

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController subclass, and I call "setEditing:animated:", but the "setEditing:animated" method of my UITableViewCells does not get called.

I have implemented the following in my UITableViewController:

```
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

And these are called when the tableview loads.

I tried manually calling [self.tableView setEditing: YES animated: YES] - so I am sure the message is getting through to the tableView, but nothing gets through to the cells.

Finally, I am aware of this similar question [TableView won't send setEditing message to cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460652/tableview-wont-send-setediting-message-to-cells) but as the answer here didn't work my problem seems to be distinct.  When I know more how it is distinct I will edit the title.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know that `-setEditing:animated:` isn't being sent to the cells? Also, please post the code where you're actually messaging `-setEditing:animated:`. The code provided is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks Mark - I know that setEditing:animated: isn't being called because I am using a custom UITableViewCell subclass and have a debugbreak in the method.  When the tableview is loaded setEditing:NO is called on all the cells, and if I override the method and change it to YES the tableviewcells do go into edit mode.  But when I call setEditing:YES animated:YES on either the tableViewController or the tableView directly after that the message doesn't make it to the cells.